# CSS font-size won't apply when using universal selector too

Tags: css, selector

I'm facing a problem with css. I'm using the `*` selector in css (I use Bootstrap and jQuery DataTable library with CSS too). In my personal CSS (indicate at last to be the most important) I have:

```
* { font-size:14px; }
.tablaJquery { font-size:10px; } /*doesn't apply in tables*/
```

The `*` selector works fine for me because is useful to reduce the navbar Bootstrap size and all this element to be in concordance with all other styles on the page.

If I indicate a style for some element to change the font-size, it works in some elements like span or div but doesn't work in tables either in the parent div of the table.

```
.tablaJquery { font-size: 10px !important; }

<table id="tablaResumen" class="table tablaJquery" style="width:100%;"> <!--still have 14px font-size-->

<div class="tablaJquery">Hello</div> <!--get 10px font-size-->
```

It doesn't work even if I insert the style in the html of the table. If I change the `*{font-size:14px;}` by `body{font-size:14px;}` the tablaJquery style works fine, but the navbar size doesn't apply the 14px font size and get different (bigger) respect others elements.

I tried to use `body{font-size:14px}` and change the navbar size separately, but doesn't work very well.

Any idea why tables don't get the specified style?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Try to set font-size to td or th elements directly, like .tablaJquery td or .tablaJquery th

Comment: try to pass the whole code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is happening because you are telling the DOM to style *ALL* elements font-size with 14px via the `universal selector`.

If you look at the debug console you'll see that the `.tablaJquery` rules are applied, but only to the element you assigned it to:

[debug picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/By9aX.png)

The 10px font-size value is not applied to the children because the universal selector is applying a rule to it already; therefore the default value of font-size, `inherit` (which is to inherit from its ancestor), is not needed and also dismissed.

In other words, the universal selector is doing something like this:

```
* > * > * etc etc
```

This can be demonstrated with your `div` example as well:

```
<div class="tablaJquery">
 <p>Hello</p> <!--get 14px font-size-->
</div>
```

Using the `*` selector [has no effect on specifity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity#How_is_specificity_calculated), but this isn't a matter of specifity, it's simply a matter that you applied a rule to all elements already, therefore they don't use their respective defaults. Tables have rows and bodies and headers and since you aren't using a more specific rule for `<td>`, they are honoring the universals rule.

There are many ways to do it with selectors, so you can take your pick, but the solution is to effectively apply the rule more specifically, like the snippet below:

```css
* {
  font-size: 14px;
}

.tablaJquery td {
  font-size: 10px;
}
```

```html
<table id="tablaResumen" class="table tablaJquery" style="width:100%;">
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Berglunds snabbköp</td>
    <td>Christina Berglund</td>
    <td>Sweden</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ernst Handel</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>Helen Bennett</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Königlich Essen</td>
    <td>Philip Cramer</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

However, for what it's worth, I think a better approach would be to set the font at `:root` or `html`. This will save you a lot of styling headaches like the one we are discussing now and, more importantly, it allows elements to use their respective defaults (*this will be crucial if you start using `em` or `rem` on other elements, or conflict with another libraries rule*.)

Here is an example of what that looks like and how the `inherit` default value applies:

```css
html {
  font-size: 14px;
}

.tablaJquery {
  font-size: 10px;
}
```

```html
<table id="tablaResumen" class="table tablaJquery" style="width:100%;">
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Berglunds snabbköp</td>
    <td>Christina Berglund</td>
    <td>Sweden</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ernst Handel</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>Helen Bennett</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Königlich Essen</td>
    <td>Philip Cramer</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```